# Using StaticGenerator to generate static HTML from a Django project

Tags: python, html, django, static

I'm trying to generate static HTML for a site I've built in Django.  What I've come up with so far is [StaticGenerator](https://github.com/luckythetourist/staticgenerator).  It looks to me like it should be similar to the example from the github page, but I have written the code below and it gives the error below.

Code:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../")))
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "site.settings"
quick_publish('/')
```

Error (edited for brevity):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    quick_publish('/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/staticgenerator/__init__.py", line 232, in quick_publish
    return StaticGenerator(*resources).publish()
  File "/dist-packages/staticgenerator/__init__.py", line 229, in publish
    return self.do_all(self.publish_from_path)
  File "/dist-packages/staticgenerator/__init__.py", line 223, in do_all
    return [func(path) for path in self.resources]
  File "/dist-packages/staticgenerator/__init__.py", line 187, in publish_from_path
    filename, directory = self.get_filename_from_path(path)
  File "/dist-packages/staticgenerator/__init__.py", line 179, in get_filename_from_path
    filename = self.fs.join(self.web_root, path.lstrip('/')).encode('utf-8')
  File "/dist-packages/staticgenerator/filesystem.py", line 38, in join
    return os.path.join(paths[0], *[path.lstrip("/") for path in paths[1:]])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 67, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, upon going through your trace, I'm going to guess your `settings.WEB_ROOT` is a tuple.

Relevant lines:

```
# web root set
self.web_root = getattr(self.settings, 'WEB_ROOT')

# web root used 
filename = self.fs.join(self.web_root, path.lstrip('/')).encode('utf-8')

# breaks on real os.path.join
return os.path.join(paths[0], *[path.lstrip("/") for path in paths[1:]])
```

Comment: Wow, that was a silly error.  I had the WEB_ROOT written with a comma at the end.  It's always the punctuation that trips me up.  :-)  Thank you!  I wish I could up vote you, but the reputation system is locking me out.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found the problem. PS: Booo. Can't even accept? I wonder if it's because I deleted the post at one point.

Comment: Thanks :) So what does it say on upvote? I'm merely curious at this point since I've never been blocked from upvoting.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation